# Separation of variables, why can't I integrate directly?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If I have the differential equation of the form

$ M(x,y) dx + N(x,y) dy = 0$

We solve it using the method of separation of variables.

But aren't $M$ and $N$ multivariable functions in two independent variables $x$ and $y$?

Why can't I integrate directly like this:

$ \int M(x,y) dx + \int N(x,y) dy = c$

And hold $y$ constant in the first integral then hold $x$ constant in the second integral?

Comment: The issue is that your original equation is not valid for all values of $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but only for those lying on an integral curve with slope $\frac{dy}{dx}$ at $(x,y).$ So your equation with the integrals is only valid along a curve, where (say) $y$ depends on $x$, and is not valid away from that curve, and you leave that curve as soon as you let the variables be independent of one another by holding one constant and integrating with respect to the other. Does that help?

Comment: Yes that makes sense! But this only works when I choose to construct the differential equation with $y$ as the dependent variable, right? That means if I wish to do that then my equation with the integrals is not valid, but what if I just wrote that equation with the integrals without stating my original goal, what would the value produce?

Comment: Then you would get an expression like $F(x,y) = C$, which defines (in general) a curve in $\mathbb{R}^2.$  Now, assuming $y=y(x)$ is a function of $x$, taking the derivative of $F(x,y)=C$ gives $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$, which is not necessarily the same as your equation at the top. The necessary and sufficient condition that you are looking for is that
$$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$$
(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential_equation).